# how do i get the keyboard input written into a txt file

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am trying to read the keyboard input and write them into a new file (a nonexistent file) line by line until a specific letter is written (-x- in this case) but it doesnt seem to be working, i keep getting errors what am i doing wrong?

```
void newfunc(){

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+");
    char char1[100], char2[100];
    int int1, int2;
    int x = 0;
    printf("Inputs\n");
    while(1) {
        scanf("%c %d %c %d", &char1[x], &int1, &char2[x], &int2);
        if ( char1[x] == "x") {
            printf("Done!");
            break;
        }
        else {
        fprintf(fp, "%c %d %c %d\n", char1[x], int1, char2[x], int2);
        }
        x++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

It creates the file but doesnt write anything into it.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: warning: comparison between pointer and integer and warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress] in line with 'if'

Comment: also it doesnt stop when i write 'x', it just keeps going

Comment: You are trying to do too many new things at once. Try some simpler things first,like accepting user input until it contains 'x', and writing a hard-coded string to a file. Master those things separately before you attempt them in tandem.

Comment: i understand your point, thank you i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Chars and strings are not the same thing.

```
if ( char1[x] == "x") {
```

should be

```
if ( char1[x] == 'x') {
```

Hard to understand why you are using arrays. Why not just have `char` variables since that's what you are trying to read.

```
char char1, char2;
int int1, int2;
printf("Inputs\n");
while(1) {
    scanf("%c %d %c %d", &char1, &int1, &char2, &int2);
    if ( char1 == 'x') {
        printf("Done!");
        break;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(fp, "%c %d %c %d\n", char1, int1, char2, int2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i actually wanted to save the inputs in an array and read from there i didnt know it would work this way, this removes the warnings, but apparently the text in newfile.txt is messed up now, doesnt seem to write properly

Comment: @karlheinzschneiderxy What do you see in newfile.txt?

Comment: `%c` does not skip whitespace by default. So maybe you should try `scanf(" %c %d %c %d"` (note the space before the first `%c`)

Comment: wow this actually works perfect with the space, just like expected, thank you so so much for your help and time, i appreciate it.